# References for the Čech-Stone compactification of Hyper-Reals?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, compactness

It seems like $\beta\mathbb R$ has been heavily studied, but I am interested in learning more about $\beta(\mathbb R ^\omega /u)$.

$\mathbb R ^\omega /u$ is a proper extension of $\mathbb R$ when $u$ is a free ultrafilter on $\omega$.  It is a special case of the hyper-real ordered field $C(X)/M^p$, where $M^p$ is the corresponding maximal ideal of $p\in\beta X\setminus \nu X$.  So the Čech-Stone compactification of these more general spaces would be of interest as well.

Any references would be much appreciated!